# PHP - Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Config in /path/to/Config.php on line 44

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a WordPress local installation that I am trying to work with. I have not written a single line of this code myself. I don't understand what this error means:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Config in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/Config.php on line 44
```

Line 44 reads as follows:

```
class Config {
```

My guess is that a `Config` class has either already been declared elsewhere, or that this file is being executed for the second time.

Comment: Find the relevant `include`/`require` and change it to `include_once`/`require_once` resp.

Comment: I have searched throughout the entire codebase and include_once and require_once are always used.

Comment: Then, the same class is defined twice in the same or, more probably, in different files. This could be a conflict between plugins and/or the active theme. Deactivate all plugins and re-activate them one by one in order to resolve the conflict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That usually happens when you declare a class more than once in a page -- maybe via multiple includes.

To avoid this, use [`require_once`](http://php.net/require_once) instead. If you use `require_once` PHP will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again.

Say, for example, you have the following code:

```
<?php

class foo {
    # code
}

... more code ...


class foo { // trying to re-declare
    #code
}
```

In this case, PHP will throw a fatal error similar to the one below:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class foo in /path/to/script.php on line 7

In this case it's very simple -- simply find the 7th line of your code and remove the class declaration from there.

Alternativey, to make sure you don't try to re-declare classes, you can use the handy [`class_exists()`](http://php.net/class_exists) function:

```
if(!class_exists('foo')) {
    class foo { 
        # code
    }
}
```

The best approach, of course, would be to organize all the configurations in one single file called `config.php` and then `require_once` it everywhere. That way, you can be sure that it will be included only once.

As for debugging the error, you could use [`debug_print_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the theme you are using refers to a file called config.php. If so use the following steps.

1. Try to find the config.php file and change it's name to configuration.php.
2. Find the files where they use config.php in the code and change it to configuration.php.